# How to filter multiple dataframe columns by same criteria with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to search for a single criteria throughout multiple dataframe columns using Python. The script I am using is not giving me the output I would hope for. The code is the following:

`df = df[df['Account Category' or 'Account Category 2' or 'Account Category 3'] == "Amazon.com and Pantry"]`

The criteria I am searching for appears in multiple columns. However, with this code, it is only showing that criteria for the first column. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, instead of saying "I want any of these 3 columns to equal something", you generally say "I want col1 to equal something, or col2 to equal something, or col 3 ..."

In pandas, you express that by combining boolean expressions like this, using `|` for `or` and `&` for `and`:

```
value = 'Amazon.com and Pantry'
filtered = df.loc[
    (df['Account Category'] == value) 
    | (df['Account Category 2'] == value) 
    | (df['Account Category 3'] == value)]
```

The pandas documentation is really good, here is a [link to the relevant](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) section explaining boolean indexing, which is what you're trying to do!

Comment: Great answer. For complex conditions it's a good idea to create them as variables c1, c2, c3, etc. Then `df.loc[c1 | c2 | c3]`. Readability! :)

Comment: Good point. Saving the mask like that also improves speed if it needs to be reused down the road!